# Codeigniter redirect URL issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am new to codeigniter. I have just made a login feature in CI with the help of google, but here I am redirecting to URL on login but It is not working.
Here is the details
after redirecting the link is like this `http://localhost/xpensepedia/index.php/home`
which is giving the 404 error

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

and my controller is

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->view('header');
        if (($this->session->userdata('user_id') != "")) {
            redirect(site_url('home'));
        } else {
            $this->load->view("register");
        }
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

My files are in the image
[image]

Comment: is your apache rewrite module enabled ?

Comment: Please show your controller code

Comment: If CI3, `user.php` need to be `User.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check name of class you given to home.php Controller

Comment: I have done nothing with home.php, home.php is just available in my view folder.

Comment: first thing. If it is Controller then it should be placed in Controller . and secondly If you are using Codeigniter 3.0  then name it Home.php You can not use redirect function to redirec on view. It redirects to controller. and I am not seeing any Home.php in your controller forlder..

Comment: you are right man, my problem was solved by making a controller for home. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can add url path on constraints ....
you define the url like this on constants :

```
define('ROUTE_STIE_PATH','localhost/xxx'); 
define('ROUTE_STIE_PATH_LOGIN',ROUTE_STIE_PATH.'login/'); 
define('ROUTE_STIE_PATH_HOME',ROUTE_STIE_PATH.'home/');
```

and then you can echo by simply

```
echo ROUTE_STIE_PATH_LOGIN
```

if you want to call any methods with in home then

```
echo ROUTE_STIE_PATH_HOME.'methodname';
```

Comment: you mean I have to make a controller for home? I just put home.php in view folder. No controller made for home.php

Comment: No. You dont have to make any home controller unless you need it for logical purpose. Have you checked out your current controller name and file name ?

Comment: I have improved my question by adding screen shot of my file hierarchy.. you can see there.. but please help me to sort this issue.

Comment: Yes I have checked.. all that you told me is fine.

Comment: I found your error when your are redirecting, the condeigniter will look for the controller first not the view. So if you want to make it right then you make a home controller and then load view home. This will work but if you want to directly load view home then ... $this->load->view("home");

Comment: let me try on new controller.. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: successfully done.. Thank you man.. can you please suggest me a fruitful tutorial website for .htaccess in CI?

Comment: because I am facing now another problem of my css, js files path.. these are working on login page but not on home page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87352/discussion-between-mohmmad-ali-and-akif-hussain-sayyed).

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public function index() {

    if (($this->session->userdata('user_id') != "")) {
        redirect(site_url('home'));
    } else {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view("register");
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

Home Controller :

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
       Public function index {
          $this->load->view('header');
          $this->load->view("home");
          $this->load->view('footer');
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. Yes It is working but then there the URL is showing like http://localhost/xpensepedia/index.php/user/login even I am logged in..

Comment: That's the current controller name... so you have to create a new controller named 'Home' and then redirect to the home controller if the session has been set. then the url would look like localhost/xpensepedia/index.php/user/home

Answer (score 0):

I solve similar case when I change my config file located in `application>config>config.php` to the following value:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```